# Reporting Server cannot decrypt the symmetric key, trying to deploy SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy my SSRS reports on our SQL Server 2014 :

> The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database.
>   You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content. (rsReportServerDisabled) Get Online Help Keyset does not exist (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090016)
>   The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database. You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content.(rsReportServerDisabled)
>   Get Online Help Keyset does not exist (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090016)

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error tells you to do? Hiw did that go? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the report server installation does not have the encryption key applied that allows it to access encrypted content in the database. If you have a backup of the current encryption key, you can apply it at the report server. I recommend determining what the likely cause is before acting. This is not something that I have found to just happen - there is usually some trigger, as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-encryption-keys-back-up-and-restore-encryption-keys).